# Method not returning the desired result

Tags: java, methods, junit, arraylist

I have included a block of code below that I just cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. The code is part of a program that I am writing that populates an array list with virtual gas station objects containing several explicit parameters; one of which is a "description" that is a String parameter being the name of the gas station. The method in question, findStation(), takes an explicit parameter that is set to the name of a gas station. Then, using this I search through my array list looking for a gas station description(using a previously declared getDescription() method that I know functions correctly) that matches my toMatch explicit parameter. If a match is found, the integer position in which it is found is returned.

Well, I feel as if I have properly written the code, but when I attempt to do a Junit test on it, I get the error "Expected <6>, but returned <-1>". Does anyone see anything immediately wrong with either my method syntax or the way I am testing the method? Thanks in advance for all the help from you wonderful people!

By the way, I have tried to include everything that pertains to figuring out the specific method in question. Let me know if something else is needed!

**Method in question: I create a temporary Station object to hold the information found at the "i" position in the list. Then, I create a temporary String to hold my description from the object I just retrieved. If the description matches the explicit parameter that is input, then I want it to return the index number at which it is found. My constant variable NO_MATCH is set equal to "-1", so my test is telling me that the gas station description does not exist when it clearly does.**

```
public int findStation(String toMatch)
{ 
    //returns the index where a match is found
    for (int i = 0; i < stations.size(); i++)
    {
        Station tmpStation = stations.get(i);
        String tmpDescription = tmpStation.getDescription();
        if (tmpDescription.equals(toMatch))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return NO_MATCH;
}
```

**Also, the addStation() method used to add stations.**

```
public boolean addStation(double inLatitude, double inLongitude, 
    String inDescription, double inPrice, String inFuelType)
{
    // Be sure inDescription is not a description in the collection
    if (this.findStation(inDescription) == NO_MATCH)
    {
        Station tmpStation = new Station();
        stations.add(tmpStation);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

**Junit test including the setup() to give you an idea of what I'm working with.**

```
protected void setUp()
{
    // collection for testing
    collection2 = new StationCollection();

    // add stations to the collection
    this.collection2.addStation(39.933611, -82.4725, 
        "Snake on the Lake", 2.99, "B80");
    this.collection2.addStation(39.9621, -83.0005, 
        "Snake Central", 2.25, "E45");
    this.collection2.addStation(39.94, -82.48, 
        "Snake Brothers", 2.27, "E45");
    this.collection2.addStation(39.8614, -82.8916, 
        "Anna Conda Oil", 2.71, "PROPANE");        
    this.collection2.addStation(39.8614, -82.8916, 
        "Anna Conda Oil - II", 2.27, "E45");
    this.collection2.addStation(39.9060, -82.7562, 
        "Tiger Snake", 2.31, "E40");
    this.collection2.addStation(39.9611, -82.9988, 
        "Rattler Ray's", 2.15, "E84");
    this.collection2.addStation(40.011792, -82.973196, 
        "Water Adder Oil", 3.20, "B80");
    this.collection2.addStation(40.011792, -82.974, 
        "Water Adder Oil - II", 2.31, "E40");
}

public void testFindStation()
{
    // Create an empty collection
    StationCollection collection1 = new StationCollection();

    // Attempt to find a station in the empty collection        
    assertEquals(StationCollection.NO_MATCH, collection1.findStation("Rattler Ray's"));

    // Use non-empty collection2

    // Look for position of matching station
    assertEquals(6, collection2.findStation("Rattler Ray's"));

    // Check that it detects a non-matching station
    assertEquals(StationCollection.NO_MATCH, collection2.findStation("Sam Snake's"));  
}
```

Comment: What is slightly confusing me here is that you sometimes use this.collection2 and sometimes you use collection2 directly. Are you sure that you do not have another (local) variable "collection2" which hides the member variable "this.collection2" ? That would explain the results you are seeing.
Did you also try to use a debugger to see what is happening? Debugging a jUnit test should be rather easy if you use a IDE.

Comment: I just looked everything over and the only place collection2 is declared is in my setUp() method in my Junit. I'm going to try and import everything I have into Eclipse and see if I can't figure out how to debug it. I'm just not very familiar with it and I am still learning.

Comment: Okay, after testing it in Eclipse and checking the variables at the point of where I'm having the problem, it appears that my addStation() method is not working correctly. My station object is not being populated with the data being passed into the 5 explicit parameters.

Comment: A good step would be to put a assertTrue around the adDStation calls in the setup method. That way you can verify that your test setup is valid or at least you get an early indicator if something breaks.

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll give that a shot when I get off of work today and get back to you if I have any further problems.